# Setting up Virtual Host with MAMP but not mapping to directory

Tags: mamp, virtualhost

I tried [following these instructions to setup a Virtual Host](https://gist.github.com/thewatts/5167719) as literally as I can.

When I try to access the directory using the virtual hostname, I get a 404 Not Found page.

I found a [post in the support forum on MAMP](http://forum.mamp.info/viewtopic.php?p=103972#p103972) saying that a possible problem I'm having is that I can't have my root folder outside of the default folder of /Applilcations/MAMP/htdocs/

Can anyone verify that this information is correct? I can't keep spending more days trying to figure this out!

EDIT: here is what I've done

Added to bottom of **httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName abc.dev
    DocumentRoot /Users/micah/Sites/abc/
  <Directory /Users/micah/Sites/abc/>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Uncommented VH entry in **httpd.conf**

```
# Virtual hosts
Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

**/etc/hosts** file, added to 127.0.0.1

```
127.0.0.1       localhost abc.dev
```

Then I restarted the servers and all I get is 404 error.

Here's the last entry in the apache_error.log within MAMP, which doesn't seem to have any relation to whether or not I try to load abc.dev because this was more than an hour ago.

```
[Wed Apr 02 23:46:38 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Apr 02 23:46:42 2014] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 11519)
[Wed Apr 02 23:46:42 2014] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Apr 02 23:46:42 2014] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Apr 02 23:46:42 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 PHP/5.5.10 mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8y DAV/2 mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.18.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

EDIT 4/4: I think I misunderstood my problem. The 404 means the hosts file is doing what it's supposed to but I can't seem to map it to the correct directory for some reason.

Comment: That information is just plain stupid: it is against the idea of a virtual host. Instead it appears to me as if you did not really understand what virtual hosts are there for. You should not navigate to a directory with the virtual hosts name...

Comment: @arkascha I need a virtual hostname in order to recreate a local version of a live site. Otherwise, I'm stuck with http://localhost:8888 and all relative paths are broken unless I match the same structure locally as it is remotely. I'd like for my virtual hostname to allow these relative paths to work properly again.

Comment: Relative paths should never get broken by relocating content. That is the whole point about relative references. The question is: by what url do you try to access that virtual host? And what is your virtual host definition? Then you can take a look at the error you get and understand and fix it.

Comment: @arkascha I'll add the info above of what I've done

Comment: @arkascha You can see all my edits to verify it's done properly.

Comment: What url do you call? And obviously: what error is in the http servers error log file for that request? Oh, and... you _did_ make sure the http server process can read and enter that directory on file system level?

Comment: the URL: http://abc.dev | In the apache_error.log file, I don't see anything referencing the preceding URL. How can I make sure the http server process can read and enter that directory on a file system level? I don't know how to find out what you said.

Comment: If you get a 404 then there _must_ be an entry inside the http servers error log file, _if_ you enabled logging at all. It might be that you have to do that separately for your virtual host and you certainly _do_ want error logging, everything else is guessing in the dark. About the permissions thing: find out what user and group id your http server process runs as (I am not that familiar with Apple, since I prefer Linux myself) and compare that against the permissions of the file system hierarchy up to the folder you specified as DocumentRoot.

Comment: I updated this question with the last entry of the error log, which is 75 minutes ago. I do not know what user and group id my http server process runs, that doesn't really make any sense to me. :/  I have no idea how to find this information out.

Comment: Well, look at the process list for example, it should be mentioned in there. There also must be a configuration for the deamon where this is configured, but I have no idea where that might be under OSX. Why does that not make sense to you? It is a process, that process belongs to a user account, the access permissions to some file system location obviously has to be granted to a user account, otherwise every user could read and write every file, this would break every security though around.

Comment: Oh, and I just see you are using `FastCGI` as opposed to the normal scripting modules, that is a very important detail, since that means that for example scripts are _not_ executed by the apache daemon directly, but by the FastCGI deamon instead. That is very uncommon, but certainly possible. So it is _that_ daemon that requires access permissions to the directory in question.

Comment: Sorry if this is confusing. But it is a non trivial setup. First step: activate error and access logging in that virtual host. No sense in guessing without.

Comment: haha, I have to admit you are talking way over my head. I don't know where this process list is, I'm not sure what you mean by configuration for the deamon, etc. This whole attempt I'm making is to avoid paying for MAMP Pro, which has this feature VH built into a their custom GUI. If I can configure it myself no need to spend the extra money. Anyway, I assume that all of MAMP's error logging is done in this apache_error.log file included in their application folder.

Comment: Sorry if this is confusing. We all learned that stuff, you will too! Let's put it this way: if you want to really use and configure such things (deamons and the like) yourself then you have to learn and understand those things. No way without obviously. I _would_ offer to give you a hand via chat or something, but as mentioned I am not familiar with the OSX platform since I prefer Linux for my daily work. You will have to dig your way through that, reading tutorials, trying around, learning things.

Comment: @arkascha I do appreciate your advice and time to write the replies! Hopefully I'll find someone familiar with what I'm trying to do via OSX and MAMP and can give me more advice.

Comment: Sure. Probably a good idea is to get access to "freenode irc" and ask there. That is the most important chat platform for usage of (mostly) free software. You won't find a better place to get assistance.

Comment: @arkascha which channel in IRC should I join where I'd get assistance? The last times I've been to channels they weren't active.

Comment: Several channels might be of interest, typically one monitors a few at the same time. I would suggest something like `##mac` or `#macdev`. About channels being "inactive": there are often periods where no one "talks", that does not mean the channel is inactive. Just ask your question in a direct but polite manner. _And be patient afterwards_. Often people see the question after 15 minutes in their backlog and reply. Absolutely no sense in repeating a question every few minutes or asking things like "Anyone?" and "Really no one can help?" IRC has its somewhat own style :-)

Comment: well, thanks for the suggestions on the channels to go but both of them say I must be invited or identified to join

Comment: Indeed the admin of those channels require you to be 'identified'. That is not the case for _all_ channels, actually only for very few on freenode irc, but typically for channels on sensitive topics or for crowded channels. Being 'identified' means a kind of login procedure against the irc server, nothing more. This means that you cannot simply pick any nickname (someone elses for examples) and start ranting in a channel, but that you actually proved that you "own" this nickname so that people can recognize you later. How to set this up depends on your irc client, it should be documented.